# Modern C++ compliant selection sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I am writing, as review, Modern C++ compliant versions of sorting algorithms I previously have seen. This post is about selection sort, and selection sort only.

Whilst selection sort is rather simple, straightforward, and not the best in terms of performance, I wanted to know if there were any ways to improve upon my implementation, especially in terms of performance:

```
// Orders a list of values by repeatedly putting the smallest
// or largest unplaced value into its final position.
template<typename T>
void sort_selection(std::vector<T> & arr)
{
    std::vector<T>::iterator min, beg, end = arr.end();
    for (beg = arr.begin(); beg < end; ++beg)
    {
        min = std::min_element(beg, end);
        if (*min < *beg)
            std::iter_swap(min, beg);
    }
}
```

I'm using local variables min, beg, end outside the loop to lower the amount of dereferencing and stack allocations and take advantage of temporal locality. Also I am using iterators and min_element, iter_swap to be modern c++ compliant.

Comment: Could be `min_element(beg+1, end)` right?

Comment: And what about support for a comparator other than `operator<`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @BenVoigt. Corbin included them in his more in-depth review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not really much code here to review, and for what it is, all I really have are some subjective stylistic concerns (I'm not a fan of omitted braces or multiple declarations per line). Instead of reviewing it as a stand alone snippet, I'm going to review it as what I would expect a fully idiomatic and generic sorting function to be in C++.

---

The biggest issue I see with this is that it's not quite up to snuff with regards to C++ idioms. It's very rare to write a method that actually takes a container (and isn't just a convenience method for the iterator version). Instead, it's customary to take two iterators since that allows you to operate on any container. In certain situations, you can even make decisions based on the iterator type. For example, you could have your sort fall back to `std::sort` if the iterator is a random access iterator.

Anyway, what I'd expect to see is this:

```
template<typename FwdIterator>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end)
{
    ...
}
```

Some people prefer just `Iter` or something similar, but I like to specify the lowest iterator requirement necessary to use the function. In this case, you just require a forward iterator.

---

Speaking of iterator types, you should use `!=` over `<` when dealing with iterator loops if all you care about is whether or not the second iterator has been reached by the first.

`operator<` might not be present on iterators in situations where `operator!=` is. This is a perfect example actually. Forward iterators are not required to define `operator<` and in fact usually won't. Other than the `std::vector` hard coding, the `beg < end` is the only thing stopping you from generalizing to a forward iterator.

---

As Ben Voigt noted, it would also be expected to generalize the comparator:

```
template<typename FwdIterator, typename Comparator>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end, Comparator cmp)
```

You would then either have the comparator default to `std::less` or you would have two functions: one that takes a comparator and one that just calls the comparator taking version with a `std::less` instance.

---

All in all, without going completely overboard, I would expect a sorting method to look something like this:

```
template<typename FwdIterator, typename Comparator>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end, Comparator cmp)
{
    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
    {
        FwdIterator min = std::min_element(beg, end, cmp); // auto if >= C++11
        if (cmp(*min, *beg))
            std::iter_swap(min, beg);
    }
}

template<typename FwdIterator>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end) {
    // using instead of typedef if >= C++11
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIterator>::value_type value_type;
    sort_selection(beg, end, std::less<value_type>());
}
```

It might be worth noting that you don't actually need two methods. I just think it's a little cleaner than this:

```
template<typename FwdIterator, typename Comparator = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIterator>::value_type>>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end, Comparator cmp = Comparator())
```

Comment: You may also want to mention that having the required `#include`s is an important (and missing) ingredient.

Comment: @Edward When it's just a snippet and not an entire program, I tend to assume the poster has required the proper headers.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of review I am looking for.
The comments on taking iterators as the parameters, using !=...

1 clarification, however, you would pass the iterators by copy since you will be manipulating them within the sort, correct?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Glad it was helpful :). Since you don't want the caller's iterators to be mutated, you need to take them by either value or const reference. Since `beg` is modified, value makes more sense. In the case of `end`, since it's not modified, it could have been taken by const reference. However, iterators are usually very cheap to copy (after all, they're usually glorified pointers), so I just took a copy.

Comment: It's a surprisingly complicated issue when it comes down to it: *What if const methods aren't defined? What if const-ref is actually less efficient than a copy?* So on. I tend to always favor value over const-ref for iterators unless I know that an expensive to copy iterator is going to be used with the function (and now that I think about it, I can't actually even remember the last time that happened).

Comment: @Corbin, tried searching for an answer without indicative results, but would be nice to add to the answer if you knew whether using modern syntax (iterators, and std functions, etc.) added any performance overhead over classic C style pointers, arrays, etc.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera That is also a surprisingly complicated question to answer. The short answer is that as long as you use C++ functionality wisely and are mindful of what's going on, it can be as efficient or even more efficient than C with regards to time/memory usage. `std::vector` is a good example of something that breaks even: as long as you're mindful of use (for example, reserving space up front instead of allowing it to grow if you know the size), once the compiler does its optimizing magic, it is essentially the same a bare `malloc()`'d array.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera `std::sort` vs `qsort` is the canonical example of a C++ thing that is more efficient than a C version. It turns out the aggressive inlining that templates can allow means that `std::sort` not only gets to be typesafe and far easier to use, but it also doesn't have to dereference a pointer and call a function with each comparison. Depending on different benchmarks/setups, some people report absurdly better numbers for `std::sort`, and I've never seen a benchmark where `qsort` is faster.

Comment: @Corbin I guess the best way to find out would be to do some performance tests.
I'm not THAT picky about the syntax, I would personally use it over C-style syntax simply for it's expressiveness and for being future-proofed, however, my curiosity can get the better of me sometime. :)

Also, I will be looking further into std::sort's magic in the future as a reference to write my own implementation using various of the algorithms i'm writing.

Comment: I have things to learn from the answer and the follow-up conversation.